# Laravel 5.3 $model->save() values are always null however mass assignment works

Tags: laravel, model, save, mass-assignment

Model

```
class Flight extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public $name;
}
```

In the controller

```
Flight::create(['name' => 'test']);
$flight = new Flight();
$flight->name = 'John';   //echo $flight->name 'John' it works
$flight->save();
```

The mass assignment creation works, however the method ->save() stores a null value for the object. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, remove the `public $name;` from your model, why you need that?

Second, of all both:

```
Flight::create(['name' => 'test']);
```

and

```
$flight = new Flight();
$flight->name = 'John';
$flight->save();
```

Is correct.

And, where are you getting that `null`?

Comment: Null is being saved into the database. I just learnt that the 

    $flight->fill(['name' => 'john])
    $flight->save(); //now it will save.

Why does it not work without the fill?

Comment: @artur is right, it's b/c you defined a `$name` property on your model, so Eloquent skips the magic where it defines your properties on the protected `$attributes` array which is what is saved to the database.

Comment: @Artur you should explain that in your answer.

Comment: I see, removing the public $name allows it to work. Originally I put it to private $name as I need to access the variables later. For example `$this->flightCode = $this->name.'-1DH'; `

Im in the habit of using getters and setters, can this still be achieved without the use of `private $name`;

Comment: Yes that'll still work without a declared `$name` property. Also, it doesn't matter if it's public or private, if there's a `$name` property defined at all, it'll skip the magic. Don't skip the magic!

Comment: @mopo922 I will never skip the magic, well from now on! cheers